PCSpim MIPS simulator keeps telling me there is an error in the code and after I remove that line it finds new errors
    .data
string: .asciiz "put the string here"

.text
main:
    li $s0, 0          # initializing the register to hold the string's length
    li $s1, 0          # initializing the register to hold the string's first half
    li $s2, 0          # initializing the register to hold the string's second half
    li $s3, 0          # initializing the register to hold the result

loop:
    lb $t0, string($s0)  # load character from string
    beqz $t0, exit      # if the string's length is 0, exit
    addi $s0, $s0, 1    # increment the string's length
    j loop

exit:
    li $s2, 0          # initializing the register to hold the string's second half

loop2:
    beq $s1, $s0, exit2  # if the string's first half is equal to its second half, exit
    addi $s2, $s2, 1     # increment the string's second half
    j loop2

exit2:
    li $s3, 1          # if the string is a palindrome, set the result to 1
    b final
    li $s3, 0          # if the string is not a palindrome, set the result to 0

final:
    li $v0, 1          # syscall code for print integer
    move $a0, $s3      # load the result into argument register
    syscall            # print the result

exit3:
    j exit3            # infinite loop

The MIPS simulator keeps telling me there is an error with message:

An error occurred while loading the file. The message are: spim:
(parser) syntax error on line 6 of file
C:\Users\HP\Documents\palindrome.asm li $s0, 0   # initializing the
register to hold the string's length"

If I remove that part of the code then it finds some new error and part of code that it didn't mention earlier. The configuration settings are all put right according to the guidelines. I have to use PCSpim_9.1.4.zip.
This was the question: A palindrome is a string that reads the same backwards and forwards. For example, each of the
following strings is palindrome: noon, civic, radar, level, and rotor. Write a MIPS program
that reads in a string from the data section and determines whether or not it is a palindrome.
Your program should declare a string in the data section as follows:
.data
string: .asciiz "put the string here"
The strings are stored in the memory according to C-style which means they are null-terminated.
A null-terminated string is a sequence of ASCII characters, followed by a zero byte (0x00).
The length of the string should be computed in the first part of the program by scanning the
characters till the null character ‘\0’ is found. The length must be stored in register r8.
The second part of the program uses the length stored in r8 and determines whether the string
contains a palindrome or not. The result must be stored in register r9 as follows: 0 for no
palindrome and 1 for palindrome.

“An error” isn’t sufficiently descriptive.

Please include relevant source in the question as formatted text rather than a link to an image of formatted text.

Loads fine here. Can't figure out what your loop2 is supposed to do. As it is it's just an infinitel loop.

Check your file for non-ascii characters maybe?

I checked for non-ascii characters and there is none...

QtSpim likes it — no errors in loading.

@ErikEidt Which configuration settings do you have on simulator?

Good question: "Accept Pseudo Instructions" is selected (and yes li is a pseudo instruction).  If you're not allowed to use pseudo instructions, you can substitute li with an equivalent but less readable addi $target, $0, immediate.

@ErikEidt  I am told that I have to use the next simulator settings: save window positions, general registers in hexadecimal, bare machine, delayed branches and delayed load. And how do I use that alternative instead of li, do I just replace that with li and then everything else after li is left or?

Oh I've got it!! I forgot that I mustn't use pseudo instructions and that's why I was getting the errors. The code works now with alternative structure.
